# Motivate why there is a point with min distance to the origin for $ 2x^3+3x^2y+2y^3=30 $, and show if there is a max.

Tags: optimization, lagrange-multiplier

Given the curve $ 2x^3+3x^2y+2y^3=30 $, motivate that there is a point closest to the origin, and show if there is a max distance.

I set up the distance function as $d(x,y) = \sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ but use $f(x,y) = x^2+y^2$ for simplicity.

I have then used Lagrange multipliers to find the local max and min for the distance function on the curve, let
$$\mathcal{L}(x,y,\lambda) = x^2+y^2 + \lambda(2x^3+3x^2y+2y^3-30).$$
And I get the equation system as:
$$\nabla \mathcal{L} = 0 \Leftrightarrow \begin{cases}
\mathcal{L}'_x = 2x+6x^2 \lambda + 6xy \lambda = 0 & (1)\\
\mathcal{L}'_y = 2y+3x^2 \lambda + 6y^2 \lambda = 0 & (2)\\
\mathcal{L}'_\lambda = 2x^3+3x^2y+2y^3-30=0 & (3)
\end{cases}$$

Which I solve  and find the (real) solutions to be $(0,\sqrt[3]{15})$ and $(2,1)$.

Now that I know that these are local min and max, how would I motivate that the min is indeed a global min? And how do I motivate that the max is not a global max?

Comment: For absolute values of $x$ and $y$ approaching infinity, we get $x^3 \approx -y^3$ or $x \approx -y$. Therefore, no global maximum distance exists.

Comment: Your solution $(2,1)$ is confirmed by [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=minimize+x*x+%2B+y*y%2C++%282*x*x*x+%2B+3*x*x*y+%2B+2*y*y*y%29+%3D+30).